# Replace comment textarea with contenteditable and parse content

Tags: jquery, wordpress, textarea, contenteditable

I'm making a new comment form for a web page and I've just configured a jQuery-based contenteditable to support text formatting for this.

The only problem is that I can't find a way to parse the content of it and send it to WordPress as if it was from the textarea#comment.

Does any one know a solution/workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to copy the contents of the contenteditable element to a hidden #comment field onblur, and post that to the comment action page.